# Programmatically test if video (m3u8 and ts) files are corrupt/not-playable

Tags: php, video

How can I programmatically go through a large list of video files (m3u8 playlist files containing keys and ts files), and test for corrupted files (or any video file that isn't playable)?

Ideally the solution isn't heavy (i.e., it can probe a segment of the video and determine its playability)?

Comment: Why are they corrupted? In general the only way to be sure a video is not corrupted is to decode it start to end.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a way for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ffMPEG or its sister ffProbe. (http://ffmpeg.org/)

The light option: ffProbe will give you information about a video and audio. Very detailed. Will do as a quick run.

The heaver option: ffMPEG can convert the video, if you tried to convert the video from one format to another then it would hopefully fail if the video was bad. But note that this a CPU intensive operation and you need to queue the requests (one instance of ffMPEG per CPU core). You can also use ffMpeg with the -i option to give you video info which is fast and "light"

You set up ffProbe or ffmpeg  on your server - it'll work on Windows and *nix systems, and you call through exec.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there are a lot of video streams that will not decode in a way that tells if they are corrupt. Unless it's a codex that contains some kind of check on the data stream.

I don't know what file formats you are referring to, but maybe the [open source getID3 library](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) for PHP will help. If it fails to extract header information then the file is likely either not a video or bad. It's also very light weight since it only checks the header.

Comment: +1 thanks! unfortunately a header check wouldn't suffice in this case.  We're explicitly providing the headers on file creation so even corrupt files will have the correct header info.  But it could come in useful for some